# Оптимизация вывода галереи изображений

Tags: javascript

Организовал на сайте галерею изображений через ajax и jquery. Код такой (отдельные участки кода прокомментировал)

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
        var links = $('#links');
        //products - массив объектов изображения, полученный ранее ajax'ом
        products.forEach(function(item){
            //добавляю html, со ссылкой на оригинальное изображание и превью изображения 300x300
            links.append('<div class="image-wrapper"> <a href="'+ item.image.path + '" title="1" class="thumbnail slide-thumbnail" data-gallery> <div class="image-preloader thumbnail-image"></div> <img class="thumbnail-image hidden" src="' + item.image.preview + '" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"</a></div>');
        });
        $('img').each(function(item, value){
            $(value).load(function(event){
                $(event.target).parent().find(':first-child').remove(); //убираю прелоадер
                $(event.target).removeClass('hidden');
                $(event.target).addClass('animated fadeIn');
            })
        })
    });
```

Собственно когда изображений > 50 чувствуются тормоза, хотя ПК у меня не слабый, браузер дает нагрузку процессору, так же сервер не успевает отдавать картинки из общей кучи, 1\2 не подругжаются, в консоли internal error выходит.

Как снизить нагрузку в таком случае?

Comment: @Alex Превью изображений и так обрезается до 300х300 или еще меньше вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Alex ну конечно я физически обрезаю, изначально у меня два урла, на оригинал и на превью  item.image.path и item.image.preview соответственно

Comment: @Alex Сайт пока на локальной машине к вечеру залью на тестовый хостинг, если что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать несколько идей для ускорения работы:

1. лучше начинать загружать картинки уже после `DOMContentLoaded`, если, конечно, галерея это не критический функционал страницы;
2. грузить первоначально желательно только превьюшки, Вам же не нужно сразу по загрузке показывать большие изображения;
3. если превьюшек больше, чем помещается во viewport страницы, загружайте сразу только те, что помещаются + небольшой запас на пару строк, остальные можно подгружать при прокрутке. В случае, когда не нравится время их загрузки, можете первоначально загрузить и добавить в DOM только те элементы, что видны, а остальные продолжить подгружать в фоне, но добавлять в DOM, только при прокрутке;
4. большие изображения показываются обычно только по клику, ничего не мешает и начинать их загружать по клику, если оно уже не было загружено, соответственно по окончанию загрузки добавить в DOM в нужное место. По скрытию большого изображения удалять его из DOM, но само изображение не удалять. Браузеру сложно отрисовывать большое количество элементов, особенно, если оно ещё и тяжелое;
5. естественно, превьюшки должны быть не масштабированные браузером большие изображения, то есть весить они должны значительно меньше большого изображения;
6. сейчас появились [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), можете использовать, когда браузер [может](http://caniuse.com/#search=promises), их для более удобной асинхронной загрузки изображений.